# NoSuchMethodError but everything seems ok

Tags: jsf, el

I am kind of new with richfaces and I am developing with richfaces 3.3.3.final in JBoss EAP 5.1.1.

I have an EAR application which is giving me this error:

```
2014-04-28 11:25:16,028 WARN  [org.richfaces.component.UIDatascroller] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) Datascroller ordenesNizaForm:tblOrdenes:scroller: The requested page #0 isn't found in the model containing 1 pages. Paging is reset to page #1
2014-04-28 11:25:16,029 WARN  [org.richfaces.component.UIDatascroller] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) Datascroller ordenesNizaForm:tblOrdenesSeleccionadas:scroller2: The requested page #0 isn't found in the model containing 1 pages. Paging is reset to page #1
2014-04-28 11:25:16,044 INFO  [ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) iniciando...
2014-04-28 11:25:16,045 INFO  [ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaBean] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) inicializando datos...
2014-04-28 11:25:16,046 INFO  [ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) ejecutar Busqueda inicial...
2014-04-28 11:25:16,056 SEVERE [facelets.viewhandler] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) Error Rendering View[/pages/main.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean ordenNizaController
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:230)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:285)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:154)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:242)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:127)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:127)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: unable to process invokePostConstruct.
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection.JBossDelegatingInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(JBossDelegatingInjectionProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:220)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.processesLifecycleCallbackMetaData(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:501)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.postConstruct(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:293)
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.injection.JBossDelegatingInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(JBossDelegatingInjectionProvider.java:90)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ec.gob.iepi.servicios.OrdenNizaServiceLocal.findOrdenesByCodigoClase(Ljava/lang/Integer;)Ljava/util/List;
    at ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController.ejecutarBusquedaInicial(OrdenNizaController.java:86)
    at ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController.iniciar(OrdenNizaController.java:57)
    ... 69 more
2014-04-28 11:25:16,100 INFO  [ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) iniciando...
2014-04-28 11:25:16,100 INFO  [ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaBean] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) inicializando datos...
2014-04-28 11:25:16,100 INFO  [ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) ejecutar Busqueda inicial...
2014-04-28 11:30:55,230 INFO  [javax.servlet.ServletContextListener] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Welcome to Seam 2.2.4.EAP5
2014-04-28 11:30:57,891 WARN  [org.jboss.seam.Component] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Component class should be serializable: sessionInfoAction
2014-04-28 11:30:57,941 WARN  [org.jboss.seam.security.permission.PersistentPermissionResolver] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.
```

I have to call this application from another one (a BPM process) using request parameters (from the URL).

My managed bean has request scope and this one has the following parameters (faces-config.xml):

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>ordenNizaController</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaController</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>ordenNizaBean</property-name>
   <property-class>ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaBean</property-class>
   <value>#{ordenNizaBean}</value>
  </managed-property>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>codigoClase</property-name>
   <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
   <value>#{param.codigoClase}</value>
  </managed-property>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>codigoSolicitud</property-name>
   <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
   <value>#{param.codigoSolicitud}</value>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>
```

Everything seems ok, I use this service to fill a list from a database (postgresql):

```
  @EJB(mappedName="ordenes-niza-EAR/OrdenNizaServiceImpl/local")
    private OrdenNizaServiceLocal ordenNizaService;
```

When I start Jboss no error appears, but in Runtime, it gets the error. And my @PostConstruct method is calling twice, I think is due to request scope.

Here is my managed bean which scope is request:

```
package ec.gob.iepi.controladores;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import ec.gob.iepi.accesodatos.AccesoDatosProceso;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.DaoException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.EntidadException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.ServiceException;
import ec.gob.iepi.modelo.OrdenNiza;
import ec.gob.iepi.servicios.OrdenNizaServiceLocal;

public class OrdenNizaController {

    private AccesoDatosProceso datos = new AccesoDatosProceso();

    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(OrdenNizaController.class);

    private String texto;
    private String codigoClase;
    private ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaBean ordenNizaBean;

    private java.lang.String codigoSolicitud;

    @EJB(mappedName="ordenes-niza-EAR/OrdenNizaServiceImpl/local")
    private OrdenNizaServiceLocal ordenNizaService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void iniciar() {
        log.info("iniciando...");
        ordenNizaBean.incializarDatos();
        if (codigoClase != null) {
            FacesUtil.setSessionMapValue("codigoClase", codigoClase);
        }
        if (codigoClase == null) {
            codigoClase = (String) FacesUtil.getSessionMapValue("codigoClase");
        }

        if (codigoSolicitud != null) {
            FacesUtil.setSessionMapValue("codigoSolicitud", codigoSolicitud);
        }
        if (codigoSolicitud == null) {
            codigoSolicitud = (String) FacesUtil
                    .getSessionMapValue("codigoSolicitud");
        }

        ejecutarBusquedaInicial();
        ejecutarBusquedaEnTemporal();
        log.info("...iniciado");
    }

    public void ejecutarBusquedaInicial() {
        log.info("ejecutar Busqueda inicial...");

        List<OrdenNiza> listaRetorno = new ArrayList<OrdenNiza>();
        try {
            Integer codigo = Integer.parseInt(codigoClase);

            ordenNizaService.findOrdenesByCodigoClase(codigo);

            ordenNizaBean.setListaOrdenNiza(listaRetorno);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            log.error("Error en la consulta del controlador", e);
        } catch (EntidadException e) {
            log.error("Error en la consulta del controlador", e);
        } catch (DaoException e) {
            log.error("Error en la consulta del controlador", e);
        }

        log.info("...Busqueda inicial ejecutada");
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public String getCodigoClase() {
        return codigoClase;
    }

    public void setCodigoClase(String codigoClase) {
        this.codigoClase = codigoClase;
    }

    public ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaBean getOrdenNizaBean() {
        return ordenNizaBean;
    }

    public void setOrdenNizaBean(
            ec.gob.iepi.controladores.OrdenNizaBean ordenNizaBean) {
        this.ordenNizaBean = ordenNizaBean;
    }

    public java.lang.String getCodigoSolicitud() {
        return codigoSolicitud;
    }

    public void setCodigoSolicitud(java.lang.String codigoSolicitud) {
        this.codigoSolicitud = codigoSolicitud;
    }

}
```

And the service implementation:

```
package ec.gob.iepi.servicios;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import ec.gob.iepi.dao.OrdenNizaDAOLocal;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.DaoException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.DeleteException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.EntidadException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.FindException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.InsertException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.ServiceException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.UpdateException;
import ec.gob.iepi.modelo.OrdenNiza;

@Stateless
public class OrdenNizaServiceImpl implements OrdenNizaServiceLocal,
        OrdenNizaServiceRemote {
    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(OrdenNizaServiceImpl.class);
    @EJB(mappedName="ordenes-niza-EAR/OrdenNizaDAOImpl/local")
    OrdenNizaDAOLocal ordenNizaDao;

    public List<OrdenNiza> findOrdenesByCodigoClase(Integer codigoClase)
            throws EntidadException, DaoException, ServiceException {
        try {
            List<OrdenNiza> listaOrdenes = ordenNizaDao
                    .findOrdenesByCodigoClase(codigoClase);
            return listaOrdenes;
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            log.error("Error en la consulta", e);
            throw new ServiceException("Error en la consulta");
        }

    }

}
```

Please your help with this.
Sorry for my english.
Thanks

OrdenNizaServiceLocal interface:

```
package ec.gob.iepi.servicios;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Local;

import ec.gob.iepi.exception.DaoException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.DeleteException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.EntidadException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.FindException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.InsertException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.ServiceException;
import ec.gob.iepi.exception.UpdateException;
import ec.gob.iepi.modelo.OrdenNiza;

@Local
public interface OrdenNizaServiceLocal {

    List<OrdenNiza> findOrdenesByCodigoClase(Integer codigoClase)
            throws EntidadException, DaoException, ServiceException;
}
```

I have other methods which are invoked correctly, the difference with this particular method is that this one uses a native query, and the other ones uses hibernate.

I am using the other methods and the application runs without problems.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these specific libraries but in general whenever I get "NoSuchMethodError" methods and it looks fine in the IDE its usually due to out of date class files. A clean-and-build often solves the problem

Comment: Why don't you show the offending code? Why exactly should we assume that your code is all fine even though you never show it in the question and the exception says otherwise?

Comment: Put `@Override` on the method in `OrdenNizaServiceImpl`. Does it compile and deploy?

Comment: I am not using an EAR file anymore, because the IDE is not taking the actual ejb classes, that's why the WAR file does not recognize that method.
Now I am using an the jar file with ejb structure and the war file separately in the same jboss instance and it's working.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

This exception is as clear as its name.
The OrdenNizaServiceLocal doesn't have the method findOrdenesByCodigoClase(Integer arg)

Extract EAR and find OrdenNizaServiceLocal.class and then decompile it, you will find that this method doesn't exist.

This could happen because of an outdated jar version.
Have a look at the jar of OrdenNizaServiceLocal class.

Comment: Thanks, but the method is declared in the class file, I have decompiled it in order to make sure if the method exists and it is

Comment: did you check for double x.y.z.OrdenNizaServiceLocal.class? under linux this command will show you the jars that have OrdenNizaServiceLocal keyword: grep -r 'OrdenNizaServiceLocal' /path/of/extracted/ear/

Comment: I did, and OrdenNizaServiceLocal is an interface, I checked it and also its implementacion (which is class too), both of them had being decompiled and the method which receives an Integer like parameter is there.

This parameter is taken from the managed bean from the URL request, this is an String, then I have to cast into Integer, but I think this is not the problem.